# Masking multiple iOS UIViews with a single UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Is it not possible to have a UIView be a maskedView to more than 1 view?  I'm setting the maskView on the following UIViews, but only the last one retains the mask setting.

```
    imageOne.maskView = viewMask
    labelThing.maskView = viewMask
    labelOtherThing.maskView = viewMask
    labelLastThing.maskView = viewMask
    labelMaskThis.maskView = viewMask //the only masked view
```

Troubleshooting this, I commented out the last line, and confirmed my suspicions.

```
    imageOne.maskView = viewMask
    labelThing.maskView = viewMask
    labelOtherThing.maskView = viewMask
    labelLastThing.maskView = viewMask //now gets the mask
    //labelMaskThis.maskView = viewMask
```

Is there a way for my `viewMask: UIView` to be applied to more than 1 view?

Comment: Can you just give each view its own mask view instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the answer is no, you can't use the same `UIView` instance to mask multiple views: apparently the masking view's layer is being integrated into the layer hierarchy of the view that is being masked.

The best way would be to create a new `UIView` mask instance for each of the views you are trying to mask. Alternatively you could copy the existing view via `NSKeyedArchiver`:

```
let archivedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(viewMask)
let viewMaskCopy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(archivedData) as! UIView
```

Although I would suggest simply creating new masking views instances the way you instantiated `viewMask` in the first place.

You may also group the masked views in a containing `UIView` in storyboard, and apply the mask to that view instead.

Comment: There's also another option, which i chose.  I nested all the views i wanted under another view in storyboard, and applied the mask to the UIView container.

Comment: Ah yes this should work, I thought you are displaying them next to each other or something.